# Tensorflow. Converting unknown dimension size of a tensor to int

Tags: python, tensorflow

Assume we have

```
a = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 3072))
b = a.get_shape()[0]
```

How can I convert **b** such that I can use it in further calculations, e.g. for given tensor **T** I will be able to create a new one, sth like

```
newT = T / b
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You have to use a Graph operation:

```
a = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 3072))
b = tf.shape(a)[0]
```

returns

```
<tf.Tensor 'strided_slice:0' shape=() dtype=int32>
```

while `b = a.get_shape()[0]`
returns

```
Dimension(None)
```

Comment: I am trying this method but I keep getting: "ValueError: Tried to convert 'x' to a tensor and failed. Error: Cannot convert an unknown Dimension to a Tensor" any solution to this problem?

Answer (score -2):

Your current way works already.  I tried it with the following code and it works fine:

```
x = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
x = tf.constant(x)
size = x.get_shape()[0]
x /= size

with googlelog.Capture():
  p_op = tf.Print(x, [x], "output: ", summarize=10)
  sess.run(p_op)
```

With output:

```
output: [0 0 1 1 1 2 2 2 3]
```

Comment: it's not my case, because your x has prespecified dimension size. And also it's a list, not a Tensor

Comment: Oh I forgot to copy and paste, but I had the line x = tf.constant(x) right after instantiation so it works for tensor.  But regarding your placeholder problem, can you elaborate what problem you have?  I would have expected the shape to be generated at runtime so above should've worked.

Comment: Oh I think I know what you are hitting.  Use tf.shape(x)[0] (which gets the value at runtime) instead of x.get_shape()[0] (which is at graph construction time)